# Nested loop with variable ranges of the inner loop in CUDA C++

Tags: cuda

I need to parallelize with CUDA a nested loop:

```
for(int ix=0; ix<Nx; ix++) {
   for(int iy=0; iy<Ny[ix]; iy++) {
      SomeFunction(ix, iy);
      ...
```

where `Ny[]` is an array in CUDA global memory. This loop is called several times in a single run, `Nx` and the elements of `Ny[]` change in different calls, and they can be large (`Nx` from 0 to about 1 million, `Ny` from 0 to about 10000).
In principle I could use a CUDA kernel with threads arranged in a two-dimensional grid of size `Nx*max(Ny)` indexed by `ix` and `iy`, so the computational cost of the kernel would be `O[Nx*max(Ny)/Ncores]`. The problem is that in my case `max(Ny)` can be larger that the average value of `Ny` by orders of magnitudes. In some calls a few elements of `Ny` can be very large (say around 1000) while most of the other elements are very small. 
I would expect a good parallel implementation of the above loop to have a computational cost of `O[Nx*average(Ny)/Ncores]`, which in my case would be much smaller than `O[Nx*max(Ny)/Ncores]`, but I do not know I to do it. I have a vague idea that a good solution could be based on first sorting the elements of `Ny`.
Just for testing purpose, here is a piece of code that produces values of Ny that have a similar distribution as mine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int UpdateArray(int *array, int *Nx);

int main()
{
  int Nx_max=1000000;
  int *Ny;
  int Nx, i;

  Ny=(int*)malloc(Nx_max*sizeof(int));
  UpdateArray(Ny, &Nx);

  for(i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", Ny[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}

int UpdateArray(int *array, int *Nx)
{
  int Nx0_min=500000, Nx0_max=1000000;
  int Nx1_min=50000, Nx1_max=100000;
  int Nx2_min=5000, Nx2_max=10000;

  int Ny0_min=1, Ny0_max=10;
  int Ny1_min=10, Ny1_max=100;
  int Ny2_min=100, Ny2_max=1000;

  int nx0, nx1, nx2, i, ix;

  nx0 = Nx0_min + rand()%(Nx0_max-Nx0_min); 
  for(i=0; i<nx0; i++) {
    array[i] = Ny0_min + rand()%(Ny0_max-Ny0_min);
  }
  nx1 = Nx1_min + rand()%(Nx1_max-Nx1_min); 
  for(i=0; i<nx1; i++) {
    ix = rand()%nx0;
    array[ix] = Ny1_min + rand()%(Ny1_max-Ny1_min);
  }
  nx2 = Nx2_min + rand()%(Nx2_max-Nx2_min); 
  for(i=0; i<nx2; i++) {
    ix = rand()%nx0;
    array[ix] = Ny2_min + rand()%(Ny2_max-Ny2_min);
  }
  *Nx = nx0;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: does `n_links` vary or is it static? please post a small numerical example input data as well as your desired output.

Comment: `n_links` varies during the simulation, i.e. it does not depend only on the index `is`, it varies with the time step `t`. I understand that the name could suggest that it is static, therefore I renamed it to `n_hits`. As I am dealing with large numbers, it would be a problem to post an example, however I edited my question and I tried to describe a numerical example. As I now say at the end, I have the vague idea that a good solution could be based on first sorting `n_hits[is]`.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more readable and of more general interest.

Answer (score 1):

If SomeFunction is much more computationally expensive that simple load and store, I would consider creating an array of int2 which would store execution parameters of SomeFunction(). Then copy this array to the device and run a kernel which would read the arguments from the array on a position indicated by thread index and execute SomeFunction() using them :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>

int SomeFunctionHost(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}

__device__ int SomeFunction(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}

__global__ void executionKernel(int2 * args, int * results,  int n)
{
    int blockId = blockIdx.x;
    int threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    if(threadId < n)
    {
        int2 myArgs = args[threadId];
        results[threadId] = SomeFunction(myArgs.x, myArgs.y);
    }
} 

int main ()
{  
    //Create execution parameters
    int Nx_max=1000000;
    int *Ny;
    int Nx, i;

    Ny=(int*)malloc(Nx_max*sizeof(int));
    UpdateArray(Ny, &Nx);

    int count = 0;
    for(i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
        count += Ny[i];
    }

    int2 * hParams, * dParams;
    int * hResults, * dResults;

    hParams = (int2*)malloc(count*sizeof(int2));
    hResults = (int* )malloc(count*sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc( (void **) &dParams, count*sizeof(int2));
    cudaMalloc( (void **) &dResults, count*sizeof(int));

    cudaMemset( dResults, 0 , count * sizeof(int));

    int index = 0;
    for(i=0; i<Nx; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Ny[i];j++)
        {
            hParams[index].x = i;
            hParams[index].y = j;
            index++;
        }
    }   

    //Copy execution parameters to the device
    cudaMemcpy(dParams, hParams, count * sizeof(int2), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Define the grid configuration
    dim3 blockDim(32,32,1);
    int gridLength = count/(blockDim.x*blockDim.y) + 1;
    dim3 gridDim(gridLength, 1, 1);

    //Run kernel
    executionKernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(dParams, dResults, count);

    //Copy the results back to the host
    cudaMemcpy(hResults, dResults, count * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //TEST
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if(SomeFunctionHost(hParams[i].x, hParams[i].y) != hResults[i])
        {
            std::cout << "WRONG RESULT !" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "DONE!" << std::endl;

    free(hParams);
    free(hResults);
    free(dParams);
    free(dResults);
    return 0;    
}
```

This way you ensure uniform distribution of work among the grid. I strongly encourage you to try different grid configurations. Maybe try parallelizing the parameters generation stage and see if it gives you any benefits. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you @pSoLT, I'll try to implement your approach, although it does not look very easy.

Comment: Hey @BrunoGolosio I extended the solution a bit. I hope it'll help you more.